# JavaScript erratic with starting point funciton

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

fairly new to js. I have a simple project in which all I have is an image twice the height of the screen. I want the webpage to open at the bottom of the page, so I have added the "window.scroll" funtion method in javascript. This works fine... most of the time. Sometimes, particularly if I test on a mobile device with a home server, the javascript just doesn't fire up and the page starts at the top. So my main question is: is there a way to do the same as "window.scroll" but with CSS, bypassing js altogether? And a second question I would have is, why is javascript so flaky? I am really new to web development and I have already twice (the other time with the "slide" method) had to use css instead of js because js doesn't work properly, or it needs to be cached etc... is this normal behaivour or just me really bad at writing it at this point? Thanks for your time. P

Here's the simple code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.scroll(0,2000);

});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
       <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/10/18/21/22/california-1751455_960_720.jpg" width="100%" style="display: block;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    window.scroll(0,2000);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the image takes time to load.So I think your event is fired however the image loads later and changes the page size again. The load event will fire after images are loaded.

try this code instead:

```
$(window).on("load", ,function(){

    window.scroll(0,2000);

});
```

Comment: Ok thanks, do I write your code instead of the $(document).ready(function() function or instead of it? I have other functions that I run inside the document.ready function

Comment: I'd also suggest using something like `window.scroll(0, document.body.clientHeight);` if you want to scroll to the bottom, that way you'll always scroll to the bottom regardless of how high the content is (i.e. you can avoid a hard coded value and let the browser work it out for you.